# Javascript change the value of the global variable

Tags: javascript

How to transfer the global variable as an actual parameter to the function to change the value of the global variable.

How to Change the Value of error

```js
function fn_check_input(reg, obj, tips, error){
        var reg = reg;
        var val = obj.val();
        if (!val){
            error = true;
            obj.next().html(tips[0]).show();
            return;
        }

        if (reg.test(val)){
            obj.next().hide()
            error = false;
        }else{
            error = true;
            obj.next().html(tips[1]).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not possible inside the function, because `error` is (presumably) a primitive. `return` the result instead, and assign the result to `error` when calling `fn_check_input`

Comment: `error` is not a global variable (in fact there are no global variables here at all), it’s a local variable defined in the function parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that I fully understand your question as it relates to global variables, but I can tell you:

Javascript is pass-by-value. Luckily, an object is just a reference, so when it is passed-by-value, you can mutate its members (since it still points to the same actual object).

You can do something like this:

```js
// @param {Object} error - error.status will be modified by this function
function mutateError(error) {
    error.status = false;
}

// error is no longer a primitive, so we can mutate it now
var error = { status: true }

console.log(error.status); // true

mutateError(error);

console.log(error.status); // false
```

As others have mentioned, you probably don't really even want to do this, and would likely be better off by just `return error;`ing.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses pass-by-value, which means changing the value of error inside of this function is only changing it's value in the scope of this function.

Perhaps consider having your function return the value that you want to store in error, and update the value of error in the calling function accordingly:

```
function fn_check_input(reg, obj, tips /*Removed Error Variable*/){
    var reg = reg;
    var val = obj.val();
    if (!val){
        //error = true;
        obj.next().html(tips[0]).show();
        return true; //Return the value of error
    }

    if (reg.test(val)){
        obj.next().hide()
        //error = false;
        return false; //Return the value of error
    } else{
        //error = true;
        obj.next().html(tips[1]).show();
        return true; //Return the value of error
    }
}
```

Now when you call the function:

```
error = fn_check_input(reg, obj, tips);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a global variable, don't worry about passing it as an argument.

```
var Test=false;
//uses global var
function F1() {
    Test=true;
}
//Test is argument, so it is no longer global.
function F2(Test){
Test=true;
}
function Click(){
F1();
alert(Test); //true. Changes to global variable work as expected.
Test=false; 
F2(Test); 
alert(Test)//false. the global variable is not changed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, if the variable is primitive type. You can pass the variable with its parent. For example:

```
function func(parent){
    parent.child = 'foo';
};
```